# angular formly inject formly in module not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

hi : formly and formlyBootstrap not inject to my module

```
angular.module('myApp', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap', function config(formlyConfig) {                
         formlyConfig.setType([
            {
             name: 'input',
             template: '<input ng-model="options.templateOptions.description"/>'
            }]);
         }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Module should be,

```
angular.module('app', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap'])
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/xgOQzz)**

Comment: thanks.with move function configuration, problem was solved. it demo helped

Comment: your code is not obvious, but demo is clear. please complete for other